# Google font issue

Tags: css, fonts

I want to give two different font-family to text like if someone type in Gujarati then font is `Mukta Vani` and English then font is `roboto`.
Is it possible..?
If someone knows then please help me.

```css
table{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; /**for english**/
}
table td{
  font-family: 'Mukta Vaani', sans-serif; /**Only for gujarati**/
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mukta+Vaani:400,500&amp;subset=gujarati" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet"> 

<table class="table grid-table table-striped  table-hover ">
  <tr><th>Title</th><th>description</th></tr>  
  <tr><td>સ્થળ નક્કી કરવું</td><td>Demo text</td></tr> 
  <tr><td>Test</td><td>Test</td></tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: Your example looks correct to me.

Comment: No now  it's not correct because English font also coming in `Mukta Vaani` font.

Comment: The Mukta font isn't converting english characters to the sanskrit, but should work if you type the characters using the sanskrit keyboard (forgive me if I have the language name wrong). The font has both english and sanskit characters: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Mukta

Comment: `Mukta Vaani` font converting in English but `roboto` is not converting in Gujarati that's why only for Gujarati letter I want to use `Mukta Vaani` font.

Comment: The font won't convert the characters, only render them. These are what's available: ​‌A​‌B​‌C​‌Ć​‌Č​‌D​‌Đ​‌E​‌F​‌G​‌H​‌I​‌J​‌K​‌L​‌M​‌N​‌O​‌P​‌Q​‌R​‌S​‌Š​‌T​‌U​‌V​‌W​‌X​‌Y​‌Z​‌Ž​‌a​‌b​‌c​‌č​‌ć​‌d​‌đ​‌e​‌f​‌g​‌h​‌i​‌j​‌k​‌l​‌m​‌n​‌o​‌p​‌q​‌r​‌s​‌š​‌t​‌u​‌v​‌w​‌x​‌y​‌z​‌ž​‌आ​‌ई​‌ऊ​‌ऋ​‌ॠ​‌ऌ​‌ॡ​‌ऐ​‌औ​‌ऎ​‌अं​‌अँ​‌क​‌ख​‌ग​‌घ​‌ङ​‌च​‌छ​‌ज​‌झ​‌ञ​‌ट​‌ठ​‌ड​‌ढ​‌ण​‌त​‌थ​‌द​‌ध​‌न​‌प​‌फ​‌ब​‌भ​‌य​‌र​‌व​‌ळ​‌श​‌ष​‌स​‌ह​‌1​‌2​‌3​‌4​‌5​‌6​‌7​‌8​‌9​‌0​‌०​‌१​‌२​‌३​‌४​‌५​‌६​‌७​‌८​‌९​‌‘​‌?​‌’​‌“​‌!​‌”​‌(​‌%​‌)​‌[​‌#​‌]​‌{​‌@​‌}​‌/​‌&​‌\​‌<​‌-​‌+​‌÷​‌×​‌=​‌>​‌®​‌©​‌$​‌€​‌£​‌¥​‌¢​‌:​‌;​‌,​‌.​‌*​‌₹

Comment: @NathanielFlick but `Mukta Vaani` also render English.

Comment: More info here on rendering Gujarati on a pc, and on the web: http://www.anirdesh.com/gujarati/gujarati-web-pages.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second font styling will always be applied. It's **more specific** than the first one as it target the `td` element. Instead you can use class for non-english text and make the english the default one for `td`.

```css
table td,table th{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; /**for english**/
}
table td.guj,table th.guj{
  font-family: 'Mukta Vaani', sans-serif; /**Only for gujarati**/
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mukta+Vaani:400,500&amp;subset=gujarati" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet"> 

<table class="table grid-table table-striped  table-hover ">
  <tr><th>Title</th><th>description</th></tr>  
  <tr><td class="guj">સ્થળ નક્કી કરવું</td><td>Demo text</td></tr> 
  <tr><td>Test</td><td>Test</td></tr> 
</table>
```

**UPDATE**

You can add a jQuery code to test if the content is english or not and then add the class :

```js
/* we suppose that english will only contain letter from a to z and numbers
   update if you want for example to consider special character, dots, quotes, etc */
var eng = /^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/;

$('td,th').each(function() {
  if (!eng.test($(this).text().replace(/\s/g, '')))
    $(this).addClass('guj');
});
```

```css
table td,
table th {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;/**for english**/
}

table td.guj,
table th.guj {
  font-family: 'Mukta Vaani', sans-serif; /**Only for gujarati**/
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mukta+Vaani:400,500&amp;subset=gujarati" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet"> 

<table class="table grid-table table-striped  table-hover ">
  <tr><th>Title</th><th>description</th></tr>  
  <tr><td >સ્થળ નક્કી કરવું</td><td>Demo text</td></tr> 
  <tr><td>Test</td><td>Test</td></tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you but it's not useful because table data is generated from database then how can I identify that text is Gujarati or English...?

Comment: @ankitapatel and in your database you are not able to know which content is in english and which one is not ? if yes you can add test on backend

Comment: no I can't identify because I don't know when someone type in English or Gujarati. There is two language available for entry.

Comment: If they typed Gujarati, that's the ANSI encoded character that will be stored in your db, if you have allowed it, then can be rendered on the screen.

Comment: I like the test!

Comment: @ankitapatel yes sure, you have to adapt the code ... as you can see in my jQuery code i target `th` and `td` so you can for example add `p`, `span`,etc ... and also update the CSS to make it working on those tags too. So the idea is simple : you target any tag with the content you want and add the class if it contains non-english content